# Minimal prime ideals contained in the Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ such that every minimal prime ideal of $R$ is principal and every minimal prime ideal is contained in either all maximal ideals or in all maximal ideals except one of them, that is, for every minimal prime ideal $p$ of $R$ we have $p\subseteq J(R)$ or there exixts a maximal ideal $m $ of $R$ such that $p\subseteq J(R)-m$. Is there any characterization for such a ring? Or is there any property for such a ring?

Comment: can you give us a concrete example of such a ring (except for trivial ones)? One trivial example would be the product of two fields. Another trivial example is a discrete valuation domain

Comment: A principal ideal domain is also probably a trivial example. @a.rajanda you should probably remove "$J(R)-M$" because taken literally that set is the emptyset. The jacobson radical is not a collection of maximal ideals. You could rephrse to "Every minimal prime lies in all maximal ideals or all except one maximal ideal."

Comment: Random thoughts: every connected commutative ring (i.e. there's a unique minimal prime ideal) is of course an example, as is every ring with at most two maximal ideals. A ring $R$ has this property iff $R/\operatorname{nil}(R)$ has this property, so we can assume wlog that we deal with reduced rings.